# Reverting a unsubmitted changelist after shelving p4

Tags: perforce, shelve

I have a changelist with large number of files. I have to work on other request so I shelved the changes using `p4 shelve -c 899`. But when I do a p4 opened the files are still showing up in workspace.

Since the number is large I want to revert all files at once. I have tried `p4 revert -c 899 *` but this didn't work(by * it is taking all files in current directory rather than the changelist).

How can this be done?

Comment: Try saying `p4 revert -c 899 //depot/...` instead.  `*` is a wildcard; it'd match all files in the current directory.

Comment: @devnull could you explain the command. Anyways it says: "//depot/... - file(s) not in client view."

Comment: `//depot/...` should be replaced by your actual depot name

Comment: Or even replaced by //...

Answer (score 4):

From the root of your client, do:

`p4 revert -c 899 ...`.  This will revert all open files in the current directory and in all subdirectories that are in changeset 899.